# Propriedade .map não consegue acessar o objeto corretamente

Tags: javascript, react

Estou conseguindo obter informações de um objeto quando acesso em certos pontos, mas um em específico não está acessível, situação:
Quando eu acesso o item.title ele retorna corretamente o valor do title, porém ao acessar o _url que está dentro de content o map retorna um erro dizendo que não pode ler a propriedade de "nulo"

```
"item": [
    {
        "title": "Serviço de poda ou corte de árvores precisa de autorização do município",
        "link": "https://g1.globo.com/ms/mato-grosso-do-sul/especial-publicitario/energisa-ms/cidade-das-arvores/noticia/2019/05/22/servico-de-poda-ou-corte-de-arvores-precisa-de-autorizacao-do-municipio.ghtml",
        "guid": {
            "_isPermaLink": "true",
            "__text": "https://g1.globo.com/ms/mato-grosso-do-sul/especial-publicitario/energisa-ms/cidade-das-arvores/noticia/2019/05/22/servico-de-poda-ou-corte-de-arvores-precisa-de-autorizacao-do-municipio.ghtml"
        },
        "description": {
            "__text": "Quem quiser solicitar o serviço pode ir pessoalmente na Central do Cidadão, em Campo Grande O morador que precisa realizar o corte ou poda de árvore, que ofereça risco dentro ou fora da residência, necessita de autorização do município para qualquer intervenção. A espécie é considerada um bem coletivo difuso no Plano Diretor da Cidade e pertence a todos. De acordo com a Secretaria Municipal de Meio Ambiente e Gestão Urbana (Semadur), se a árvore estiver dentro do quintal ou na calçada, nenhum tipo de poda pode ser feito sem a prévia autorização do órgão público. A superintendente de gestão ambiental da Semadur, Gisseli Giraldeli, também explica que o morador tem autonomia para realizar a poda ou corte, desde que a autorização do serviço tenha sido concedida pela prefeitura. Serviço de poda ou corte de árvores precisa de autorização do município Divulgação “A necessidade da intervenção é avaliada por técnicos da prefeitura. Nessa avaliação é feita a verificação do grau de urgência desse trabalho. São incluídos como prioritários aqueles que têm maior grau de risco, já que hoje a demanda é muito grande frente ao recurso que temos para atender”, ressaltou Giraldeli. Ainda conforme a superintendente, em caso de árvores que estão em logradouros públicos, calçadas, canteiros, parques, a prefeitura é a responsável por executar a intervenção. Quem tiver interesse em solicitar o serviço deve comparecer à Central de Atendimento ao Cidadão (CAC), que fica na rua Cândido Mariano, nº 255, no centro de Campo Grande. Para o procedimento é necessário abrir um processo administrativo apresentando documentos pessoais e a localização precisa das árvores. Somente o proprietário do imóvel ou representante legal poderá fazer o requerimento.",
            "__cdata": "\r\n<img src=\"https://s2.glbimg.com/BRe8LbOPe1QUGzQDb7jh7REcMTI=/i.s3.glbimg.com/v1/AUTH_59edd422c0c84a879bd37670ae4f538a/internal_photos/bs/2019/r/Z/ryOg0kS0WpxCBGbryAVQ/imagem.png\" /><br />\r\n"
        },
        "content": {
            "_url": "https://s2.glbimg.com/BRe8LbOPe1QUGzQDb7jh7REcMTI=/i.s3.glbimg.com/v1/AUTH_59edd422c0c84a879bd37670ae4f538a/internal_photos/bs/2019/r/Z/ryOg0kS0WpxCBGbryAVQ/imagem.png",
            "_medium": "image",
            "__prefix": "media"
        },
```

Enquanto escrevo o próprio editor reconhece a o _url corretamente como string existente.

[image]

Enfim em execução este é o erro

[image]

Abaixo um snippet com uma versão reduzida do objeto demonstrando que a função map encontra o link corretamente com esse JS mas ao executar no contexto do React(que está comentado logo abaixo do funcional) retorna erro de referência

```js
var rssflat = {
  "rss": {
   "channel": {
    "title": "G1",
    "link": [
     "http://g1.globo.com/index.html",
     {
      "_href": "http://pox.globo.com/rss/g1/",
      "_rel": "self",
      "_type": "application/rss+xml",
      "__prefix": "atom"
     }
    ],
    "description": "Últimas notícias de economia, política, carros, emprego, educação, ciência, saúde, cultura do Brasil e do mundo. Vídeos dos telejornais da TV Globo e da GloboNews.",
    "language": "pt-BR",
    "copyright": "© Copyright Globo Comunicação e Participações S.A.",
    "image": {
     "url": "https://s2.glbimg.com/veNWQCjPmWVRAfzfLSJt35f_V58=/i.s3.glbimg.com/v1/AUTH_afd7a7aa13da4265ba6d93a18f8aa19e/pox/g1.png",
     "title": "G1",
     "link": "http://g1.globo.com/index.html",
     "width": "144",
     "height": "144"
    },
    "item": [
     {
      "title": "Serviço de poda ou corte de árvores precisa de autorização do município",
      "link": "https://g1.globo.com/ms/mato-grosso-do-sul/especial-publicitario/energisa-ms/cidade-das-arvores/noticia/2019/05/22/servico-de-poda-ou-corte-de-arvores-precisa-de-autorizacao-do-municipio.ghtml",
      "guid": {
       "_isPermaLink": "true",
       "__text": "https://g1.globo.com/ms/mato-grosso-do-sul/especial-publicitario/energisa-ms/cidade-das-arvores/noticia/2019/05/22/servico-de-poda-ou-corte-de-arvores-precisa-de-autorizacao-do-municipio.ghtml"
      },
      "description": {
       "__text": "Quem quiser solicitar o serviço pode ir pessoalmente na Central do Cidadão, em Campo Grande O morador que precisa realizar o corte ou poda de árvore, que ofereça risco dentro ou fora da residência, necessita de autorização do município para qualquer intervenção. A espécie é considerada um bem coletivo difuso no Plano Diretor da Cidade e pertence a todos. De acordo com a Secretaria Municipal de Meio Ambiente e Gestão Urbana (Semadur), se a árvore estiver dentro do quintal ou na calçada, nenhum tipo de poda pode ser feito sem a prévia autorização do órgão público. A superintendente de gestão ambiental da Semadur, Gisseli Giraldeli, também explica que o morador tem autonomia para realizar a poda ou corte, desde que a autorização do serviço tenha sido concedida pela prefeitura. Serviço de poda ou corte de árvores precisa de autorização do município Divulgação “A necessidade da intervenção é avaliada por técnicos da prefeitura. Nessa avaliação é feita a verificação do grau de urgência desse trabalho. São incluídos como prioritários aqueles que têm maior grau de risco, já que hoje a demanda é muito grande frente ao recurso que temos para atender”, ressaltou Giraldeli. Ainda conforme a superintendente, em caso de árvores que estão em logradouros públicos, calçadas, canteiros, parques, a prefeitura é a responsável por executar a intervenção. Quem tiver interesse em solicitar o serviço deve comparecer à Central de Atendimento ao Cidadão (CAC), que fica na rua Cândido Mariano, nº 255, no centro de Campo Grande. Para o procedimento é necessário abrir um processo administrativo apresentando documentos pessoais e a localização precisa das árvores. Somente o proprietário do imóvel ou representante legal poderá fazer o requerimento.",
       "__cdata": "\r\n<img src=\"https://s2.glbimg.com/BRe8LbOPe1QUGzQDb7jh7REcMTI=/i.s3.glbimg.com/v1/AUTH_59edd422c0c84a879bd37670ae4f538a/internal_photos/bs/2019/r/Z/ryOg0kS0WpxCBGbryAVQ/imagem.png\" /><br />\r\n"
      },
      "content": {
       "_url": "https://s2.glbimg.com/BRe8LbOPe1QUGzQDb7jh7REcMTI=/i.s3.glbimg.com/v1/AUTH_59edd422c0c84a879bd37670ae4f538a/internal_photos/bs/2019/r/Z/ryOg0kS0WpxCBGbryAVQ/imagem.png",
       "_medium": "image",
       "__prefix": "media"
      },
      "category": "G1",
      "pubDate": "Wed, 22 May 2019 20:43:20 -0000"
     }
      ]
   },

  }
 }
  
rssflat.rss.channel.item.map((item, i) =>{
      return console.log(item.content._url);
    })
    
//{rssflat.rss.channel.item.map((item, i) =>{
//        return ( 
//    <Card>
//     <img src={item.content._url} alt="Imagem"/>
//     <a href={item.link}>{item.title}</a>
//    </Card>
//    );
//      })
//    }
```

Comment: Não vejo nada de errado. Pode ver nesse sandbox que mostra a imagem normalmente: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-dew-od35c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estou deixando a solução aqui para caso ocorra com mais alguém esse tipo de desatenção à estrutura do objeto: 
O problema estava ocorrendo pois alguns objetos "item" não possuíam o objeto "content", e por eu não ter feito um tratamento de caso ele tentava ler uma propriedade que não existia, no snippet não ocorreu erro justamente por só ter um objeto e este ter o content, substituí a linha:

```
<img src={item.content._url} alt="Imagem"/>
```

por

```
<img src={item.content? item.content._url : null} alt="Imagem"/>
```

Comment: se essa é a resposta certa marque ela como resolvida

Answer (score 0):

Você esta mapeando um array de objetos, cada objeto é mapeado dentro de "item", então você esta tentando acessar o _url dentro do primeiro objeto, porem ele só existe dentro do segundo, é onde estora o erro, se o mapeamento continuasse dessa maneira ele tentaria acessar .title e .link dentro de cada item, daria outro erro pois eles só existem no primeiro.

Resumindo seu item recebe "`{
                        "title": "Serviço de poda ou corte de árvores precisa de autorização do município",
                        "link": "https://g1.globo.com/ms/mato-grosso-do-sul/especial-publicitario/energisa-ms/cidade-das-arvores/noticia/2019/05/22/servico-de-poda-ou-corte-de-arvores-precisa-de-autorizacao-do-municipio.ghtml",
                        "guid": {
                            "_isPermaLink": "true",
                            "__text": "https://g1.globo.com/ms/mato-grosso-do-sul/especial-publicitario/energisa-ms/cidade-das-arvores/noticia/2019/05/22/servico-de-poda-ou-corte-de-arvores-precisa-de-autorizacao-do-municipio.ghtml"
                        }`", como pode ver _url não existe neste json;

Uma solução seria você colocar todas as propriedades dentro de um mesmo objeto, ou não utilizar map no seu item, e sim tentar acessar diretamente, ...item[2].content._url